# Better way to perform bulk CRUD operations in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on an asp.net application which allows a user to upload a CSV file and read and update values in SQL table. Typically there could be 500 records and 8 parameters.

Using sqlbulkcopy, CSV file can be directly uploaded into table. But this option requires to write all logic in another stored procedure and call it after bulk copy.

If there are any other approaches I could follow to acheieve this, please let me know.

Note: Table parameter is not an option, since its SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS?

Comment: @Raj, I am afraid SSIS is not a option for me.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what would be an acceptable answer since a bulk load and SSIS is not an open (really unclear why SSIS is not an option).  However if you're just looking for something to do the CRUD for you: http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=12

Comment: How about reading the file stream and making it XML or custom objects and querying it?

Comment: You could also read the objects and treat them as detached objects reattach them with EF, but I suspect that's not an option either.

Comment: Okay... this is my last comment... what do you expect to magically happen?

Comment: Have you written something already and it's too slow?

Comment: @DanAndrews: Passing it as XML is another option, thanks.

Comment: Since results should be instant, I can't use SSIS.

Comment: I am looking into other option of DataSet too. This seems to be reasonable one.

Comment: You can programmatically fire off SSIS